# Determine Prime Attributes In this relation. Functional Dependencies are given

Tags: dbms

Relation is R(P,Q,C,A,B)
R has the following functional dependencies:
F = { P→QC , CA→B , Q→A , B→P }
What are the prime attributes

Comment: Why is this closed ?  It's most definitely a question about "database modeling and design".

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this kind of question is found by determining all the candidate keys based on the FD's as stated.  Do you know how to do that ?  If so, do so and pls show the results you obtained, if not, try to apply the axioms/theorems of FD theory [recursively] until you get FD's that are minimal on the LHS and maximal (all attributes) on the RHS.  The most useful axioms/theorems in this exercise are transitivity and unions :

If X->Y and Y->Z then X->Z (and therefore X->YZ).
If X->Y and P->Q then XP->YQ.

(And if X,Y,P,Q denote *sets* of attributes then the more precise version is
If X->Y and P->Q then X U (P \ Y) -> Y U Q.)

If that doesn't help, then I'm afraid the answer here must be "this site is not do_my_homework_for_me.com" ...